# What is the relationship between susceptibility to subclinical secondary immune response and susceptibility to colonization?

Tags: infection, epidemiology

[Damien, Scheider, and Muller 1998](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9700638) looks at susceptibility to secondary immune response in vaccinated and unvaccinated people. Is it reasonable to infer, from susceptibility to subclinical secondary immune response, a susceptibility to colonization?

Comment: I think it would be difficult to eliminate problems and concerns of original antigenic sin.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow.